# Node.js, find the largest of pairs

Tags: arrays, node.js

For Node.js, how can I find ["5",0.668574], being the largest in below:

[[["0",0.0137134],["1",0.0156018],["2",0.142732],["3",0.14874],["4",0.0151308],["5",0.668574]]]

Thanks !

```
Finally figured out with the help of Piyush N. Thanks Community !

var pairs = [[["0",0.0137134],["1",0.0156018],["2",0.142732],["3",0.14874],["4",0.0151308],["5",0.668574]]];

var max = ((pairs [0])[0])[1];
var maxPair = (pairs [0])[0];  
pairs[0].forEach(pair => {
    if(pair[1] > max) {
    max = pair[1];
    maxPair = pair;
  }
});

console.log(maxPair);
```

Comment: show us what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pairs = [["0",0.0137134],["1",0.0156018],["2",0.142732],["3",0.14874],["4",0.0151308],["5",0.668574]];

var sumOfMaxPair = parseInt((pairs[0])[0]) + (pairs[0])[1];
var maxPair = pairs[0];

pairs.forEach(pair => {
  var sumOfCurrentPair = parseFloat(pair[0], 10) + pair[1];
  if(sumOfCurrentPair > sumOfMaxPair) {
    sumOfMaxPair = sumOfCurrentPair;
    maxPair = pair;
  }
});

console.log(maxPair);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Piyush! That helps a lot!

I might have misled you, the first item in a pair is meant to be string, I wish to get the pair with the largest second item. Following you logic, I figured it out as follows, and it works!

Note that the original var pairs have one more set of [], as compared to your.

```
var pairs = [[["0",0.0137134],["1",0.0156018],["2",0.142732],["3",0.14874],["4",0.0151308],["5",0.668574]]];

var max = ((pairs [0])[0])[1];
var maxPair = (pairs [0])[0];  
pairs[0].forEach(pair => {
    if(pair[1] > max) {
    max = pair[1];
    max = max;  
    maxPair = pair;
    maxPair = maxPair;
  }
});

console.log(maxPair);
```